# How to i do an age calculator in JS

Tags: javascript

im making a js app that ask for your age an integer and tells you what generation you are i Think i need to take each generation and but each generation age in an array then use if else to print the right generation name, am I on the right track as far as thinking

i want the input taken to be the age i have the arrays but now idk what to do with them

```
const Alpha = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,]
const Genz = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
const Mill = [26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,]
const boom = [42]
```

Comment: e.g.:  `if (Alpha.includes(age))` ...   But perhaps better to get the year of birth.  e.g.: `if (yob >= 1981 && yob <= 1996)`... Then your program still works correctly next year.

Comment: but you're not  on the right track as far as thinking about age **range** (for example age 40.5 wouldn't fit)

Comment: Forget that you are programming. Don't think of arrays and loops. Think about how **you** would solve this problem in your head if you were asked by someone. E.g. "To which generation does Andrea belong, who is 20 years old?" Your answer: "Easy, Gen Z!" Now you are asked "Why? How did you come to this conclusion?" I don't think your answer would be "Because 20 belongs to the list [10, 11, ... 24, 25], which is Gen Z."

Comment: You can also have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/bv1d3L8t/2/. I believe you won't need to maintain the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Run the user input (yyyy) through a chained ternary.

```
let generation = yearOfBirth > 2010 
&& 
yearOfBirth < 2026 ? 'Generation Alpha' 
:
```

If yearOfBirth is greater than 2010 `>`

AND `&&`

yearOfBirth is less than 2026 `<`

then return 'Generation Alpha' `?`

else if... `:`

```js
document.forms.generations.onsubmit = findGen;

function findGen(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const IO = this.elements;
  
  let yob = parseInt(IO.YoB.value);

  let gen = yob > 2010 && yob < 2026 ? 'Generation Alpha' :
  yob > 1995 && yob < 2011 ? 'Generation Z' :
  yob > 1980 && yob < 1996 ? 'Millennials' :
  yob > 1964 && yob < 1981 ? 'Generation X' :
  yob > 1945 && yob < 1965 ? 'Baby Boomers' :
  yob > 1927 && yob < 1946 ? 'The Silent Generation' :
  yob > 1900 && yob < 1926 ? 'The Greatest Generation' : null;
  IO.view.value = gen;
}
```

```html
<form id='generations'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Year of Birth (1901 - 2025)</legend>
    <input id='YoB' type='number' min='1901' max='2025' required>
    <button>Done</button>&nbsp;
    <output id='view'></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```